# Is the given figure correct? Does the electron really flow out as depicted by the arrow?

Tags: electrochemistry, electrons

[image]

Someone up here questioned about the figure and that the arrow is pointless and doesnt make sense? Or is it?

Comment: See also CH SE META post about [policy for "Am I right?" questions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3396/policy-on-amirite-questions)

Comment: Both arrows are correct: conventional current flow is defined as from more positive to less positive. It is the opposite of electron flow. Blame Ben Franklin for this convention.

Comment: It would be better if the legend showed arrows as “net movement of negative charge”, and there were another arrow in the salt bridge. The transport mechanism in the wire is distinct from that in solution, yet there is a frequent misconception that free electrons move through the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The direction of electron flow as shown in the figure is correct, however, as the reduction potential of Zn is -0.76 V and that of Cu is 0.34 V the resultant cell potential obtained by
E cell = E cathode - E anode.
E cell = 0.34-(-0.76) = 0.34+0.76 = 1.1 V.
For this to happen the Zn(s) electrode must get oxidized to Zn2+ ions giving up electron to Cu electrode as denoted by the arrow. On the other hand the Cu2+ ions present in the cathodic compartment take up the electrons coming through wire in the copper electrode and get reduced to Cu(s). However, in the figure the arrows drawn in the solution part of the figure are not correct.
The arrow for anode compartment(containing Zn electrode) should show movement of Zn atoms from electrode to electrolyte solution as Zn2+ after oxidation.
The arrow for Cathode compartment (containing Cu electrode) should show movement of Cu2+ ions from electrolyte solution to the electrode as deposited Cu metal after reduction.

Comment: The arrows are correct: see my main comment.

Comment: It sounds like you are assuming that the arrows at the electrodes are intended to show the direction of flow of *ions*, but the figure label clearly indicates those arrows represent *electron* flow, for which the indicated direction is correct.

Comment: I also find that the yellowish arrows in solution are confusing. The electrons originate in the Zn and Zn ions shed into solution and electrons are 'consumed' in the Cu metal by combining with Cu ions. The electrons do not flow through the solution as is suggested by the arrows in the figure.

Comment: in solution there are no electrond, conduction takes place because of ions. Therefore using arrows to show electron movement in solution is technically incorrect